# Incorrect validation of rows in 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, validation, multidimensional-array, boolean-logic, tic-tac-toe

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm making a simple game similar to Tic-Tac-Toe. We have a square game field (2D array) with random size of it's side. It may look like:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]
```

Here is one of the methods to check out the matches for rows:

```
boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] field) {
  boolean valid = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < field[i].length; j++) {
      if (!field[i][0].equals(field[i][j]) && !field[i][0].equals("[ ]")) {
        valid = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return valid;
}
```

And there is a problem in it. Method works correclty for usual cases, for example, like:

```
[ ] [ ]  O
 X   X   X 
[ ]  O  [ ]
```

But if the game field is empty or the first column is empty, as following,

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]    [ ]  X  [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]    [ ]  X  [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]    [ ]  X  [ ]
```

result of `checkHorizontal(String[][] field)` is `true`, but should be `false`, because there are no matches in rows here, and I really don't know how to fix this.

**Update.** The answer of @David Choweller helped me. I altered his method a little bit, but in general it's the same thing:

```
boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] field) {
        boolean valid = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals("[ ]")) {
                continue;
            }
            int j;
            for (j = 1; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                if (!field[i][j].equals(field[i][0])) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == field[i].length) {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: Your logic seems odd. Your if is saying: if not all of the elements of a row are the same and if the first element is not empty it is invalid.

Comment: You probably want: if not all of the elements of a row are the same or if the first element is empty it is inalid

Comment: So your if should be: `if (!field[i][0].equals(field[i][j]) || field[i][0].equals("[ ]"))`

Comment: @EliSadoff If I do so, result is `false`, despite the fact that values of a row are equal.

Comment: @EliSadoff I've tried `if (!field[i][0].equals(field[i][j]) && field[i][0].equals("[ ]"))`, but it's also incorrect for empty field (we are getting `false`).

Comment: Are you empty fields actually `"[ ]"` or `""`?

Comment: @EliSadoff `"[ ]"` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to return true if you find any horizontal row consisting of all Xs or all Os, and your empty field is the string `"[ ]"` this should work:

```
boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] board) {
    final String emptyCell = "[ ]";

    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        String firstElementInRow = board[row][0];
        if (firstElementInRow.equals(emptyCell)) {
            continue;
        }
        int column;
        for (column=1; column < board[row].length; column++) {
            if (!board[row][column].equals(firstElementInRow)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (column==board[row].length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just checking it horizontally why not just take the first element of each row and compare it with the next two element of the same row and return `true` else `false`.

```
public static boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] field) {
    boolean valid = false;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        String s = field[i][0]; //first element of each row 
        if (s.equals(field[i][j + 1]) && s.equals(field[i][j + 2]))
            return true;
    }
    return valid;

}
```